# Can I use git rebase with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git, git-rebase

I have found an in-depth discussion of why it is problematic:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2012/Sep/msg00356.html

Has anyone got a successful workflow for rebasing commits on an Xcode project with multiple developers?